# Does kill(SIGSTOP) take effect by the time kill() returns?

Tags: linux, unix, signals, child-process

Suppose I have a parent process and a child process (started with e.g. fork() or clone()) running on Linux.  Further suppose that there is some shared memory that both the parent and the child can modify.

Within the context of the parent process, I would like to stop the child process and know that it has actually stopped, and moreover that any shared memory writes made by the child are visible to the parent (including whatever synchronization or cache flushes that may require in a multi-processor system).

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35985529/4086593), which speaks of using kill(SIGSTOP) to stop a child process, contains an interesting tidbit:

> When the first kill() call succeeds, you can safely assume that the child has stopped.

Is this statement actually true, and if so, can anyone expound on it, or point me to some more detailed documentation (e.g. a Linux manpage)?  Otherwise, is there another mechanism that I can use to ensure that the child process is completely stopped and is not going to be doing any more writes to the shared memory?

I'm imagining something along the lines of:

1. the parent sends a different signal (e.g. SIGUSR1), which the child can handle
2. the child handles the SIGUSR1 and does something like a pthread_cond_wait() in the signal handler to safely "stop" (though still running from the kernel perspective) -- this is not fully fleshed out in my mind yet, just an idea

I'd like to avoid reinventing the wheel if there's already an established solution to this problem.  Note that the child process needs to be stopped preemptively; adding some kind of active polling to the child process is not an option in this case.

If it only existed on Linux, pthread_suspend() would be perfect ...

Comment: *the child does some mutex/cond magic in the signal handler to let the parent know that it's stopped*  A stopped process can't do anything - by definition.

Comment: "the parent sends a different signal (e.g. SIGUSR1)" so the child wouldn't truly be stopped from the kernel perspective, just waiting in e.g. pthread_cond_wait() -- I'll edit the question to clarify

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [POSIX documentation on Signal Concepts](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_04) strongly suggests, but does not explicitly say, that the targeted process will be STOPped by the time `kill()` returns:

> A signal is said to be "generated" for (or sent to) a process or thread when the event that causes the signal first occurs... Examples of such events include ... invocations of the *kill()* and *sigqueue()* functions.

The documentation is at pains to distinguish signal *generation* from *delivery* (when the signal action takes effect) or *acceptance*.  Unfortunately, it sometimes mentions actions taken in response to a stop signal upon generation, and sometimes upon delivery.  Given that *something* must happen upon generation *per se*, I'd agree that the target process must be STOPped by the time your call returns.

However, at the cost of another syscall, you can be sure.  Since you have a parent/child relationship in your design, you can [`waitpid()/WUNTRACED`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/wait.html) to receive notification that your child process has, indeed, STOPped.

**Edit**

See the other [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58920294/132382) from [that other guy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1899640/that-other-guy) [sic] for reasons why you might *not* want to do this.

Answer (score 3):

It definitely sounds like you should be using a custom signal with a handler, and not sigstop.

It's rare not to care about the state of the child at all, e.g. being fine with it having stored 32bits out of a single non-atomic 64bit write, or logically caught between two dependent writes.

Even if you are, POSIX allows the OS to not make shared writes immediately visible to other processes, so the child should have a chance to call `msync` for portability, to ensure that writes are completely synced.

Comment: Thanks, this is a good recommendation and I initially accepted it as the answer -- pilcrow answers the original question more directly though.